# How to instantiate GameObject at random collision free position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, gameobject

I am making a game in Unity. I am instantiating (circle) `GameObjects` on random positions and it works well. What I am trying to do is to instantiate only on positions where there will be no overlapping with other `GameObjects`. No solution that I have found on the internet solved my problem so what should i do? Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. In order to detect if there is space for your circle you will need to use either a collider or a mathematical/volume equation. But whichever way you do this you will need to reference a position(transform x,y,z) to sample an area and determine if your circle can be spawned there.

You could do one of the following:

1. Create the object as you normaly would, but if there is a collision immediately destroy the object. Then spawn another.
2. Move a spawner gameobject in a location which does the same check as above but only when it has been determined there is room for the circle do you spawn it. (*edit*) Then disable or move the spawner, you will only need one of these objects to do all your spawning.
3. Have whichever class spawns the circles pick from an array of predefined positions(a vector 3 or existing gameobjects in the scene) then perform one of the checks above.

It depends of your needs and how likely an overlap is.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Method 2 is better, but it should be improved in order to avoid unnecessary instantiating/destroying of GOs - the spawner is a game object in the Hierarchy which is never destroyed, it has a circle collider of the right radius, and it's used, by feeding the new randomized position to its `Transform`, to check if such position is free of other objects - if yes, then you can instantiate the new game object, if not, choose another random position until you get a free one.

Comment: I agree, number two is much better and less wasteful than method 1. I like your solution of having the spawner object moving around to check if it is a suitable spawn position. It is sort of where I was going with the third point but better thought through.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Method number 2 suites my needs the best. 
So you mean that i create a transparent gameObject and if there is no coliision when spawned, destroy the transparent one and spawn the real one on that possition. If there is a collision, destroy transaprent one and try on other position. Am i right?

Comment: Well if you follow Galandil's advice you would not need to destroy the spawner it would simply be disabled and you would use the same one whenever you need to spawn a circle. Then you are not destroying/ instantiating things all over the place which is costly. But yes a transparent object, just needs to be empty except a few things like a collider.

Comment: Your spawner GO is just a GO with only a `Circle Collider 2D` component on it, so it doesn't render anything on screen. You generate the random position, change the `transform.position` of the spawner, and check if the `OnTriggerEnter2D` report a collision - if not, `Instantiate` a new game object using that position, if yes, generate a new random spawning position and repeat until you get a free space.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if these objects you instantiate are few and not very frequent, this solution is ok. If you're going to instantiate and destroy a lot of circles with a high frequency, then a simple object pooling system would be better, deferring the check directly to the soon-to-be-activated GO in the pool.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! But @Galandil, yes there will be many circles in high frequency that will be destroyed on click, so you suggest me the 3rd method?
I tried this by adding positions to an array and on every spawn i check wheter the position does not match the ones from array, but no success.

Comment: There's a video tutorial on how to create an object pooling system in Unity: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling - check it out. For a generic text tutorial about object pooling, read this: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

Comment: Also each object from the pool can manage its own "spawning" by checking where it can spawn before doing so. But to stress you don't actually need to instantiate the object, just to re-position it if using object pools.

Comment: Hello, its me again, i decided to use the second method, but how to check if  onTriggerEnter reports collision? I tried using bool, but its allways set like there is collision even if there is not so is there any better way? @Mr.Bigglesworth

Comment: Well you have your method like so:
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        Debug.Log("Hello, a collision occurred!! ");
    }

Comment: So in the above, every time a collision happens to the object this script is on it will fire the method. and in this case post this console message. Now you need to ensure that the collider on the same object as the script is set to be a trigger (tickbox)

Comment: If you keep getting a collision and there is nothing there make another question around it with a screenshot and your script and we can go through it